# GeoServer WFS CSV without header

Tags: geoserver, wfs, csv

Is it possible to execute a GeoServer WFS request that returns CSV without a header?

Example:

```
https://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=topp:states&outputFormat=csv
```

Will return a comma separated list of all attributes of `topp:states` but includes a header row. Is it possible to make this request so that the header is excluded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not as the code stands at present. I can't really see a use for a CSV file without the header row, it's just a bunch of random numbers then.

You could ask for an enhancement to the CSV output format but please read these [guidelines](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-new-features-and-improvements-in-GeoServer) first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My use case is a scenario where we have to make two requests to the same layer. If we didn't get enough records from the first request we need to pull more from the second...which means we need to append the two csv lists together. Which is simple enough to do but would be easier if we could ask for the second list without a header. Appreciate it though!